# Do any Christian denominations prevent their congregations from having Christmas pageants?

Tags: comparative-christianity, christmas

Given the fact that a Christmas pageant isn't complete featuring the Wise Man dropping in on the Holy Family in the manger [is unbiblical](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/23369/what-is-the-basis-for-the-belief-that-the-wise-men-did-not-arrive-in-bethlehem-u) do any denominations specifically prevent their congregations from having those plays?  Are there any other reasons to anathematize purveyors of Christmas pageants?

Comment: Perhaps I’m not getting the point of your question. As I’m sure you know Jehovah’s Witnesses do not allow any of the Christmas customs as we believe all are of pagan origin.  https://www.jw.org/en/publications/magazines/wp20151201/christmas-customs/

Comment: @kris - that's a good answer.  I don't know much about Jehovah's Witnesses, I know they don't participate in Christmas customs, but I never knew why. Not sure how a Christmas pageant would be a pagan custom though.

Comment: Besides the issue of Christmas customs, there's also the problem that some have with [representations of Jesus](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/45468/21576).  But I don't know how rigidly this is enforced.

Comment: There are also some churches that dislike acting in general, but they are pretty rare.